# Data de useState no persiste al actualizar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usestate

Estoy trabajando con la barra de búsqueda de mi sitio de peliculas.
Tengo un estado en el cual guardo la data que traigo de la api de TMDB y luego eso lo muestro en una grilla de peliculas.
El problema es que, si luego cliqueo cualquiera de esas pelis para ver sus detalles y después vuelvo para atrás, o actualizo la página, ya no se ven todas las pelis, es decir, no persiste el estado.. y no entiendo cómo hacer para que esto no pase...Alguna ayuda?

La página me dice que estoy detallando poco, pero es que este es el problema en si..
Lo que quiero lograr por si no me expliqué bien, es que la información traída de la API persista incluso cuando refrezco la página para que se sigan mostrando los resultados de búsqueda anteriores.

```
//búsqueda de peliculas
  const [search, setSearch] = useState([]);
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([]);

  let newSearchArr = [];
  let finalSearchArr = "";



  //convierte espacios en %20 para poder buscar peliculas con espacios en la API de TMDB
  const prepareSearch = (toModify) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
      if (toModify[i] !== " ") {
        newSearchArr.push(toModify[i]);
      } else {
        newSearchArr.push("%20");
      }
    }
    finalSearchArr = newSearchArr.join("");
    return finalSearchArr;
  };

  if (search){
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=f4f465d2995b1b9d521de6be4a2c8f18&language=es-ES&query=${prepareSearch(
          search
        )}&page=1`
      )
      .then((res) => res.data.results)
      .then((searched) => setSearchResult(searched));
  }



  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=f4f465d2995b1b9d521de6be4a2c8f18&language=es-ES&query=${prepareSearch(
          search
        )}&page=1`
      )
      .then((res) => res.data.results)
      .then((searched) => setSearchResult(searched));
  };

  const handleNameChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  return (


    //PELICULAS

    <div className="layout m-5">
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3 className="title is-3">Buscar Peliculas</h3>
        <br></br>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
          <Form.Control className={styles.input} onChange={handleNameChange}
            value={search}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Ingrese el nombre completo o una parte del mismo"
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <br></br>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Buscar
        </Button>
      </Form>
      <SearchGrid searchResult={searchResult}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Como inicial tu peticion deberia estar en un useeffect y segundo, usas la misma grid para mostrar todas las peliculas y la que possteriormente eliges?

Comment: Hola Hernán! Gracias por responder. Uso un grid para toda la grilla de peliculas y después 1 componente "Card" para los detalles de cada pelicula.

Answer (score 0):

El estado de React no es persistente. Para lograr lo que usted quiere debe usar alguna estrategia de cache desde el browser como por ejemplo `localStorage` o `sessionStorage` dependiendo de sus requerimientos.

```
if (search){
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=f4f465d2995b1b9d521de6be4a2c8f18&language=es-ES&query=${prepareSearch(
          search
        )}&page=1`
      )
      .then((res) => res.data.results)
      .then((searched) => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('search', searched);
        setSearchResult(searched)
      });
  }
```

Por otro lado podría hacer que se ejecute nuevamente el servicio de películas de esta forma siempre que el usuario actualice podrá encontrar nuevos items en el caso que la data cambiase frecuentemente, de lo contrario siempre estará mostrando data desactualizada.